# Set default Date of Birth in Private Class

Tags: java

I wish to create a private variable with a default date of birth, in this case, January 1st, 2000. Where is the error here? (I'm using `import java.util.Calendar;`)

```
private Calendar birth = Calendar.set(2000, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What's a "default date of birth"? Which people have that? Does it actually make sense to set a default?

Comment: The `set()` method is not static. And it has no return value.

Comment: Also, it's better to use the newer `java.time` APIs

Comment: Also: don't model a date of birth with a `Calendar`, which models an instant in time (consider that two people born at the same instant in time in different time zones can have different dates of birth, and travelling to a different time zone doesn't change your date of birth). Use a `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, `Calendar` doesn't have a `static` method for `set`, it's an instance method (meaning you will need to create/get an instance of the class before you can use it)

Having said that, since it's 2019 now, there is very little excuse to still be using it (especially since even if you're still using Java 7 or below, there are libraries available which back port the new `java.time` API) and instead, you should be using  the newer `java.time` API instead.

```
private LocalDate birth = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 0)
```

or

```
private LocalDate birth = LocalDate.of(2000, Month. JANUARY, 0)
```

which is less ambiguous and easier to read.

The newer library makes it much easier to do things like, calculate the amount of time between to points in time, so you could calculate the age of the person based on their date of birth and now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Calendar.set` does not exist as a static method. You must first get an object that is an instance of `Calendar`, and then you can call the `set` method to make it have your desired date.

```
private Calendar birth = Calendar.getInstance();

{
    birth.set(2000, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This terrible class `Calendar` was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For the purpose here, `LocalDate`.